# Log4j2 not working on Tomcat istance

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I've made a war of my spring boot project that have the following structure.

```
base  
 +---logs  
 +---AuthorizationService 
 |  
 +----src -> main ---> java ---> com.project -> (classes)
                   |
                   +-> resources
                          |
                          +---->application.properties & log4j2.xml          


 +---ResourceService
 |  
 +----src -> main ---> java ---> com.project -> (classes)
                   |
                   +-> resources
                          |
                          +---->application.properties & log4j2.xml
```

After the war build (as you can see the projects have due main modules)
I've uploaded it on a tomcat.
I've found the logfiles in the relative path specified , but when i do something on the app that normally trigger a log message, these files don't respond.

Here's the configuration via xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration monitorInterval="60" status="WARN">
<Properties>
    <Property name="logsRoot">${sys:catalina.home}/logs</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>

    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="LogFileAll" fileName="${logsRoot}/AuthorizationLogsAll.log" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>

    </File>

    <File name="LogFileError" fileName="${logsRoot}/AuthorizationLogsError.log" immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>

    </File>

    <!--
    <RollingFile name="LOGFILEALL" fileName="${logsRoot}/application.log" filePattern="${logsRoot}/application.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>

        <Policies>
            <sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>

        <DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="4" />

    </RollingFile>
    -->
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAll"/>
    </Root>

    <logger name="com.pcsystem" level="info" additivity="true">

        <appender-ref ref="LogFileError" level="warn"/>
        <!-- ogni log message marcato con PCSYSTEM_CONSOLE sara' inserito nella console
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT">
            <MarkerFilter marker="PCSYSTEM_CONSOLE" onMatch="NEUTRAL" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </appender-ref>
        -->
    </logger>

    <!-- opzioni per i loggers del contesto apache tomcat
    <logger name="org.apache" level="info" additivity="true">
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAll" />
    </logger>
    -->
</Loggers>
```

I have 2 files of configuration 1 for module that target the same path.
Why my app doesn't speak?
Normal logs that in local environment never appear on the log file on "catalinahome"/logs
I've found the log file populated only with start message

**EDIT**
hey f1sh, you're showing me the light at the end of the tunnel, because the module structure seems to be different.

Actually launching pwd command on tomcat bash i've recovered this path:
home/intranet/tomcat/webapps/intrane-0.0.1/web-inf/classes

inside classe we have the xml but also application.properties. other files and the COM package that lead to
com.project.[...] classes

Is a configuration path problem?

Comment: In which folder in the .war do your log4j configs end up?

Comment: i'll edit the main post for better formatting